# Why does count(false) return 1 in PHP?

Tags: php

How does `count(false) === 1` make any sense at all since `count(null) === 0`?

> count — Count all elements in an array, or something in an object.
>   -http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

This makes even less sense since booleans are primitives and not arrays or `countables`.

Comment: And that's just how it was defined: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L285

Answer (score 1):

`count` returns the number of elements. `false` is one element (a boolean) but `null` is nothing, `null` is not a value.

Note that you can destroy a variable, for example an item in an array by setting it to `null`:

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$a[1] = null;
var_dump(isset($a[1]));
```

You will obtain `false` because `$a[1]` is no longer defined.

If you do the same with false:

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$a[1] = false;
var_dump(isset($a[1]));
```

You will obtain `true` because `$a[1]` is set to the boolean `false`

Comment: Actually if you read the source of `count()` that @mario posted than anything that is not null, an array or object returns 1. Which is just plain weird for a function that preparedly counts arrays and countable objects. 
Your example is a completely different case, $a is actual array. `FALSE` is a primitive boolean value - not a element of an array. An example of this would be if you have a function `get_rows_from_db` that gets a number of rows from the database or returns false if the query fails. You would expect `if (count(get_rows_from_db())) {}` to be sufficient...

Comment: instead of if (is_array($result) && count($result)). Even returning -1 would make more sense.